# Issue with Azure Web App from Docker Compose only showing Nginx Homepage

Tags: azure, flask, nginx, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I've been having an issue deploying my project on an azure web app now for days and haven't been able to solve it. I feel like it's so close to working but there seems to be an issue with the way nginx seems to be serving my flask app. My azure website only shows the nginx landing page:

[image]

I'm using the Azure Web App "Docker Compose (Preview)" to deploy this app. The registry source is coming from my Docker Hub repository. My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
    image: tracrux/irelandwindfarms
    command: gunicorn wsgi:app --bind 0.0.0.0:5000
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}:/flaskapp/
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}static:/flaskapp/static
    ports:
      - "5000"


  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}static:/flaskapp/static
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - app

volumes:
  static:
```

I'm not sure if this is a bad idea, to have the dock-compose file build my app from the context and then pull the image from dockerhub also. I'm guessing my context part is redundant here anyways since it will just get overwritten by the image. Also for the "${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}" (which azure web app logs screamed at me I needed in my volume path) I have set this in a .env file as WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME=./
"./" is what the path was set to locally when it was working, so I was just trying to replicate this.My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.12 # set the working directory 
WORKDIR /flaskapp # install dependencies 
COPY ./requirements.txt /flaskapp 
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt # Copy your Flask application code 
COPY . . 
EXPOSE 5000
```

My nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1000;
}

upstream my_site_proxy {
  server app:5000;
}

http {
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  https://irelandwindfarms.azurewebsites.net/;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://my_site_proxy/;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /flaskapp/static/;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried everything I can find online to solve this issue. I have reconfigured my docker-compose.yml, dockerfile and nginx.conf so many time now and no matter what I do I can't see to get it to work. Here are my Deployment Center logs which indicate everything is working normally:

```
2024-03-15T18:00:11.445Z INFO - Starting multi-container app..
2024-03-15T18:00:12.038Z INFO - Pulling image: tracrux/irelandwindfarms
2024-03-15T18:00:13.417Z INFO - latest Pulling from tracrux/irelandwindfarms
2024-03-15T18:00:13.427Z INFO - Digest: sha256:dbb401c5936d150717e74541d1fc53419dcdd330929599eccbb4c8e00dd321a4
2024-03-15T18:00:13.429Z INFO - Status: Image is up to date for tracrux/irelandwindfarms:latest
2024-03-15T18:00:13.439Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 1 Seconds
2024-03-15T18:00:13.488Z INFO - Starting container for site
2024-03-15T18:00:13.490Z INFO - docker run -d --name irelandwindfarms_app_0_cad2ad5c -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=irelandwindfarms -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=irelandwindfarms.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=11af5b4880bcafd0e33c899dd84747a89c767943adf0db58295f85ef997b95d4 tracrux/irelandwindfarms gunicorn wsgi:app --bind 0.0.0.0:5000
2024-03-15T18:00:13.504Z INFO - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2024-03-15T18:00:13.928Z INFO - Pulling image: nginx:latest
2024-03-15T18:00:15.054Z INFO - latest Pulling from library/nginx
2024-03-15T18:00:15.101Z INFO - Digest: sha256:6db391d1c0cfb30588ba0bf72ea999404f2764febf0f1f196acd5867ac7efa7e
2024-03-15T18:00:15.105Z INFO - Status: Image is up to date for nginx:latest
2024-03-15T18:00:15.120Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 1 Seconds
2024-03-15T18:00:15.154Z INFO - Starting container for site
2024-03-15T18:00:15.155Z INFO - docker run -d -p 8362:80 --name irelandwindfarms_nginx_0_cad2ad5c -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=irelandwindfarms -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=irelandwindfarms.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=11af5b4880bcafd0e33c899dd84747a89c767943adf0db58295f85ef997b95d4 nginx:latest
2024-03-15T18:00:15.157Z INFO - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2024-03-15T18:00:22.966Z INFO - Started multi-container app
2024-03-15T18:00:22.972Z INFO - Initiating warmup request to container irelandwindfarms_nginx_0_cad2ad5c for site irelandwindfarms
2024-03-15T18:00:22.974Z INFO - Container irelandwindfarms_nginx_0_cad2ad5c for site irelandwindfarms initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
```

Anyone have any ideas of what the issue might be I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, made some changes, and was able to deploy it to Azure via dockerhub without any issues.

My **docker-compose.yml:**

```py
version: "3"
services:
app:
build:
context: ./
image: tracrux/irelandwindfarms
command: gunicorn wsgi:app --bind 0.0.0.0:5000
volumes:
- .:/flaskapp
- ./static:/flaskapp/static
ports:
- "5000:5000"
nginx:
image: nginx:latest
volumes:
- ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
- ./static:/flaskapp/static
ports:
- "80:80"
depends_on:
- app
volumes:
static:
```

**nginx.conf:**

```py
events {
worker_connections 1000;
}
http {
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name irelandwindfarms.azurewebsites.net;
location / {
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_pass http://app:5000;
proxy_redirect off;
}
location /static/ {
alias /flaskapp/static/;
}
}
}
```

**Dockerfile:**

```py
FROM  python:3.12
WORKDIR  /app
COPY  requirements.txt  requirements.txt
RUN  pip  install  -r  requirements.txt
COPY  .  .
EXPOSE  5000
CMD  ["python",  "wsgi.py"]
```

Here's the local output:
[image]

[image]

Run the below commands to push the docker images to docker hub.

```
docker login
```

Tag your Docker image with your Docker Hub username and repository name:

```
docker tag your_image_name:latest your_dockerhub_username/your_repository_name:latest
```

Push the tagged image to Docker Hub:

```
docker push your_dockerhub_username/your_repository_name
```

while creating the web app choose docker container as the publish option and provide required details

[image]

Here's the Azure app service output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Sirra, really appreciate your feedback. However, I have a question around why you used "Single Container" option when deploying the web app. Would this not mean that Azure is not reading from the docker-compose.yml file and is just reading the normal Dockerfile. And would this not also mean that the nginx reverse proxy is not being deployed in it's own container?

Comment: @user101 I had previously used the default option, but now when selecting the publish option, I don't see a Docker container. Instead, there's a container where I can't find the Docker Compose (preview) option.

Comment: Previously, we had options like [this](https://i.imgur.com/FYxOx1l.png) but now it has changed to [this](https://i.imgur.com/QdZu1tJ.png)

Comment: I've deleted my old web app to start fresh but I still see [this](https://imgur.com/a/QIkiPeE). I wonder why you're getting a new version.